# Doing Ajax with JSP

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I am doing a Ajax in JSP Application
I am using 2.0.

My code:

```
<f:view>
    <h:form>

        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{ user.username }"></h:inputText>

        <h:commandButton value="Load" >
            <f:ajax execute="name" redner="outputname"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:outputLabel id='outputname' value="#{ user.username }"></h:outputLabel>

    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

Some error happen and I dont know the reason.

```
The tag f:ajax is only available on facelets.
```

and

```
/index.jsp (line: 17, column: 3) No tag "ajax" defined in tag library imported with prefix "f"
```

Comment: What tag library do you have in your page that equates to "f" ?

Comment: yes , <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>

Comment: i think you are mixing jsp and jsf2. Remember that in jsf2 you does not support jsp! You should do something like this 
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">`, Read this http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_ajax.html

Comment: you are right :D I found that too, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
<h:head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
        content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>

        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{ user.username }"></h:inputText>

        <h:commandButton value="Load" >
            <f:ajax execute="name" redner="outputname"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:outputLabel id='outputname' value="#{ user.username }"></h:outputLabel>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```